# How to add JSON Parser libraries?

Tags: android, json, web

I want to use the JSONParser codes but when I write the codes some imports are wrong or it's marked by red.What I have to do?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try using the volley library. this will remvoe all your headache of using the JSONParser class to get the json from the url and so on.**

Please refer this link for volley:

**http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/**

.. Let me know if this helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the dependency to your project? If not, write this line to your build.gradle file

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0-beta3'
```

For Http Client, add this dependency for your project:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
```

Besides, that library was deprecated. You should use HttpUrlConnection instead.

**TIP:** If you want to import some library (dependency), just copy that library package(e.g. org.apache.http.HttpEntity) + "dependency" then type to Google :D

Comment: it can be harmful for me?

Comment: No, but they recomend to use the new one because it better. You also can use the old

Comment: you can try to put this line below your buildToolsVersion in gradle file: `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fast Android Networking Library

1. Add this dependency to your build.gradle (app level) 
   `compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0'`
2. Add internet permission in manifest
3. **For GET Method**

   AndroidNetworking.get("https://fierce-cove-29863.herokuapp.com/getAllUsers/{pageNumber}")
                .addPathParameter("pageNumber", "0")
                .addQueryParameter("limit", "3")
                .addHeaders("token", "1234")
                .setTag("test")
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                     // do anything with response
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void onError(ANError error) {
                     // handle error
                   }
               });

**For POST method**

```
AndroidNetworking.post("https://fierce-cove-29863.herokuapp.com/createAnUser")
             .addBodyParameter("firstname", "Amit")
             .addBodyParameter("lastname", "Shekhar")
             .setTag("test")
             .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
             .build()
             .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                  // do anything with response
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                  // handle error
                }
            });
```

documentation here: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

Answer (score 0):

While adding JSONParser you may get some errors, kindly do this two step:

For me the path was like: C:\Users\vaidu\Instructable2\app\build.gardle

Add this two things to buildgradle file

1. android {
       useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}
2. dependencies{ compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' }